# Couchbase .NET SDK does not work with default Testcontainer

Tags: c#, .net, couchbase, testcontainers

I want to create bucket and use couchbase SDK together with Testcontainers. When writing basic code for setting up the container and create bucket I getting not very detailed exception.

```
 Couchbase.Core.Exceptions.KeyValue.SocketNotAvailableException:ChannelConnectionPool
    at Couchbase.Core.ClusterContext.GetOrCreateBucketLockedAsync(String name)
    at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in \ConsoleApp4\ConsoleApp4\Program.cs:line 24
```

Code to repro:
Csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CouchbaseNetClient" Version="3.4.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Testcontainers" Version="3.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Testcontainers.Couchbase" Version="3.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Program.cs

```
using Couchbase;
using Testcontainers.Couchbase;


const string TestBucketName = "Test";

CouchbaseContainer CouchbaseContainer
    = new CouchbaseBuilder()
        .Build();
try
{
    await CouchbaseContainer.StartAsync();
    var options = new ClusterOptions
    {
        UserName = CouchbaseBuilder.DefaultUsername,
        Password = CouchbaseBuilder.DefaultPassword,
    };

    var connectionString = CouchbaseContainer.GetConnectionString();
    var cluster = await Cluster.ConnectAsync(connectionString, options);

    var bucket = await cluster.BucketAsync(TestBucketName);
    var collection = await bucket.DefaultCollectionAsync();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    await CouchbaseContainer.DisposeAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(e);
  
}
```

I tried to create bucket from the UI and it worked.

EDIT: After digging a bit, I see that main cause of this is that `ChannelConnectionPool`  was disposed just before I want to create a bucket. This is callstack of that method:

```
    at Couchbase.Core.IO.Connections.Channels.ChannelConnectionPool.Dispose()
    at Couchbase.Core.ClusterNode.Dispose()
    at Couchbase.Core.ClusterContext.BootstrapGlobalAsync()
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.AsyncStateMachineBox1.ExecutionContextCallback(Objects)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.AsyncStateMachineBox1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.AsyncStateMachineBox1.MoveNext()
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.<>c.<OutputWaitEtwEvents>b__12_0(Action innerContinuation, Task innerTask)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.ContinuationWrapper.Invoke()
    at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(Action action, Boolean allowInlining)
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject)
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task1.TrySetResult(TResult result)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.SetExistingTaskResult(Task1task, TResult result)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.SetResult(TResult result)
    at Couchbase.Core.ClusterNode.GetClusterMap(Nullable1configVersion)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.AsyncStateMachineBox1.ExecutionContextCallback(Objects)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.AsyncStateMachineBox1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.AsyncStateMachineBox1.MoveNext()
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.<>c.<OutputWaitEtwEvents>b__12_0(Action innerContinuation, Task innerTask)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.ContinuationWrapper.Invoke()
    at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(Action action, Boolean allowInlining)
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject)
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task1.TrySetResult(TResult result)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.SetExistingTaskResult(Task1 task, TResult result)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.SetResult(TResult result)
    at Couchbase.Core.ClusterNode.ExecuteOp(Func4 sender, IOperation op, Object state, CancellationTokenPair tokenPair)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.AsyncStateMachineBox1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
    at System.Threading.ThreadPool.<>c.<.cctor>b__87_0(Object state)
    at Couchbase.Core.IO.Operations.OperationBase.HandleOperationCompleted(SlicedMemoryOwner1& data)
    at Couchbase.Core.IO.Operations.OperationBase1.Couchbase.Core.IO.Operations.IOperation.HandleOperationCompleted(SlicedMemoryOwner1& data)
    at Couchbase.Core.IO.AsyncStateBase.SendResponseInternal(Object response)
    at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallbackDefaultContext1.Execute()
    at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
    at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()  
    at System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback()
```

EDIT 2:
After digging even more I found out that this piece of code in ClusterContext class in BootstrapGlobalAsync method:

```
if (GlobalConfig.UseAlternateAddresses)
{
    node.Dispose();
}
```

Its disposing the node. After hardcoding that to false it started to work.

Comment: Can you print out e.ToString ? It should have the stacktrace and more information.

Comment: @MichaelReiche done.

Comment: Great. Where is it? Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: @MichaelReiche I digged a bit,  and I see that main cause of this is that ChannelConnectionPool was disposed just before I want to create a bucket. I Updated the post with both stacktraces.

Comment: I opened an issue https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/NCBC-3545

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the `CouchbaseNetClient` version `3.4.12`. Although I spent quite a while trying to assist @couchbaseuser without success, I gave it another try and checked the client versions. I encounter the same error. Downgrading the client to `3.4.3` resolves it.

Comment: Do you know if this is restricted to Testcontainers? It has not been observed in on-premise or Capella environments.

Comment: No, I do not. Pre-configuring Couchbase is pretty complex. Of course, it still could be a Couchbase misconfiguration. Considering the TC module has not changed, I guess it is likely related to the client. Luckily, it is easy to reproduce using TC.

Comment: Ok, it looks like Testcontainers uses localhost and alt addressing, so therin lies the bug - we haven't seen that yet. I pushed a patch and this will be resolved in 3.4.13 to be released on or aorund 11/04/2023. Note that downgrading the client to 3.4.3 isn't the solution, but a work-around. Downgrading to 3.4.11 is a better wrok around IMO.

Comment: That was quick, thanks .

Comment: NCBC-3545 is fixed in 3.4.13 which is live on NuGet as of this morning 11/09/2023